# How to execute external js files synchronously in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension. Extension uses at least ten javascript  files. All the JS files are included in background.html in order that they are required to be executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/one.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/two.js"></script>
.
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/ten.js"></script>
```

one.js makes an asynchronous XmlHttpReques and thus takes some time to complete the execution.

**My Problem is** - Before one.js is completely executed two.js gets executed, which I don't want, since two.js refers to some of the objects from one.js.

**Note:** I can not use inline JS in background.html & can not make a synchronous XmlHttpRequest in one.js

Thanks.

Addendum: Example ajax function

```
function myFunction () { 
    $.ajax({ 
      url: chrome.extension.getURL("../../data.json"), 
      dataType: "json", 
      beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"); 
      } 
    })
    .success(function (widgetJson) { // some code }) 
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { // some code }); 
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to utilize promises or deferreds from `one.js` to `two.js` at all?

Comment: R. A. Lucas,
I am new to JS and not aware of these concepts, let me go through them n try it out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you show what your xhr code that you're waiting on looks like?

Comment: `function myFunction () {$.ajax({
            url: chrome.extension.getURL("../../data.json"),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
            }
       })
        .success (function (widgetJson) {
                // some code
         })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            // some code
        });
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a namespaced function that you can call in `two.js`, so something like:

```
window.App = App || {};

var myAjaxFunction = function myAjaxFunction() {
  return $.ajax({...include ajax stuff here...})
    .success(function(data) { 
      ...//do something...
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      ...//handle error
    });
}; 

App.ajaxPromise = myAjaxFunction();
```

and then in `two.js` resolve it similar to how you already are, like:

```
$.when(App.ajaxPromise)
  .then(function(data) {
    ...//do more stuff
  });
```

Hope this helps.  Best.

Comment: Above solution did not help. Now, instead of JSON I have put all the data in JS file, this way I can just refer to js object & no need to read JSON.

Comment: Okay, because it's an extension you may have to use messaging to communicate between scripts, check out this doc: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging